# React Native DatePicker Specific Hours

Tags: react-native, momentjs, tcomb

Is there a way in React native to choose specific hours in the date picker ?
for example here in the [DatePickerIOSe](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html), we can choose `mode: time`. and there are two other Props (maximumDate, minimumDate) , is there a way to specify those to just hours and minutes for example
`maximumDate = new Date('12:00:00')` or something like that?

Comment: You can below code, hope Its work;

https://snack.expo.io/@erdemildiz/4e9a4d?session_id=snack-session-ZDoH8nrTn

Comment: That solved it, I'm writing an answer with the complete code so anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @erdemildiz said, we can solve this easily by `setHours()` and `setMinutes()`
Here is a code using Tcomb to make a timer from 10:00:00 to 22:00:00

```
    var startTime = new Date()
    startTime.setHours(10)
    startTime.setMinutes(0)
    var finishTime = new Date()
    finishTime.setHours(22)
    finishTime.setMinutes(0)

    timer: {
          label: 'select time',
          maximumDate: finishTime,
          minimumDate: startTime,
          minuteInterval: 10,
          mode: 'time',
          config: {
            format: (date) => { return moment(date).format('HH:mm A') },
            defaultValueText: 'Choose time',
          }
        }
```